# C++ Most efficient way to store mutable binary data in a variable?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, memory-management, binary

I'm working with a stream of binary strings and I'd like to assign this data to datatypes in the most memory-efficient way.

Example: `int` uses `4bytes` for a range of `-2147483648 to 2147483647`

Since my data is just ones and zeros, what is the best datatype to use for a large stream of binary data?

I've tried using bitset, but running functions like reading and substituting `0001 for 1` and `0101 = 5` runs slower compared to integer datatypes.

Is there any other efficient way to store and traverse binary data in a data type?

Comment: What's best for an arduino will be completely different than what's best for a mainframe with several thousand CPUs. You will need to keep doing what you were doing: trying different alternatives and seeing which ones work "best" for your specific use case, on your hardware, with your compiler, and your operating system.

Comment: don't use `int` when you care about number of bytes. Try fixed width integers instead https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am not using Arduino. I'm just talking about a simple windows machine with avg specs.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes that is a good approach but again the data is just binary so integer values end up using the extra space too right?

Comment: what extra space?  "`int` uses 4bytes" is not correct in general. `int` is the wrong type when you want to store bits and bytes because its width can vary between target platforms

Comment: Okay, so only specific int types. What is the largest datatype that can fit data in cpp?

Comment: Didn't realize avg was still making computers. You sure that's not your antivirus?

Comment: There is no defined limit to the size of an integer datatype in C++. Each implementation is allowed to specify their own size with [a few simple rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) like a minimum size and stuff like `long` can't be smaller than `int`. Sam wasn't kidding in his first comment. Different systems have different sizes, byte orders, and other crazy smurf.

Comment: The question doesn't have enough to answer even for an "average windows box." Performant data structures are always shaped by the kind and frequency of operations done on them. For example, if you'll get the data once, edit individual randomly indexed bits a gajillion times, then send the result out over a network, the answer is likely to be very different than if you're searching for a given bit pattern and setting it to zero, etc. etc.  @SamVarshavchik is right about needing to experiment. Guesses about what will be work well are only good to within a factor of 10 or so in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `char*`

If you're looking for performance use just a byte array (`char*` or `char[]`). Try to use high level functions to move/copy the data(memcpy, memmove etc.) It's the interaction with bits that make things slow. Avoid them as much as possible.

You'll get huge speed boosts if the data is byte aligned. You can do things like reinterpret_cast for the pointer type (`int* int_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(char_ptr); int my_int = *int_ptr;`). If it's not, because space might be higher piority, still use high level functions to see large speed boosts. Something like

```
unsigned int *int_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(char_ptr*);
unsigned int my_int = *int_ptr >> offset_bits + *(int_ptr+1) << (sizeof(int) * 8 -offset_bits);
```

Also compile with `-O2` to let the compiler do magic and maybe make your code faster.

Always make sure you're you have control over the size of the data and not let it be \0 ended or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you mean by "more efficient way" is the one that minimizes the [Shannon information entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)).

A very common way to encode data in order to minimize said entropy is by using [variable length codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code).